# Change the width of active slide, when having slidesPerView

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

How to change the width of active slide, when having slidesPerView: 3. (Swiper JS) if a change to auto, slides are not centered.

[Example on codepen] (https://codepen.io/salezr/pen/wvqLgzB)

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      centeredSlides: true,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      initialSlide: 1,
      pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true
      }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to set active slide width, when slidesPerView: 3. Must be center and show 3 slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008547/how-to-set-active-slide-width-when-slidesperview-3-must-be-center-and-show-3).

Answer (score -2):

You need to do this in JavaScript:

```
centeredSlides: true
```

Then you can choose the active slide with this:

```
class .swiper-slide-active
```